# IE8 Randomly does not show background images of my divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have this annoying problem driving me nuts, IE 8 randomly won't show background images of my divs. One minute it shows, then the next time it won't. Then I have to refresh the page 2-3 times for it to show.

All my pages work fine on firefox, chrome.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Any solutions?

Comment: Please post an example link or show some code.

Comment: Are the background images somehow generated by a script or something?

Comment: no the images are not generated by script, its hard to give an example 'cuz its random...if i just give html page it works fine....it looks like the problem alysko has posted below....i'll try and see if that solution works

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but the image would never show in IE8, regardless of how many times I refreshed the page.  It worked fine in Chrome and FF (latest versions as of the time of this post).

The image file was created in Adobe Illustrator (CS3) and saved as a JPG.  It turned out to be file corruption of the JPG that I resolved by opening the file in Paint.NET, saving as a GIF, opening the GIF and re-saving as a JPG.  The issue does have to do with IE8 but Paint.NET had problems with the file as well.  I could not save the original JPG as a JPG; I had to switch to another format and then back.

I hope this helps those with the issue I ran in to.